# Submitting Google Form Response from Code Behind (Issue: Date)

Tags: javascript, datetime, google-apps-script, timezone, google-forms

I have a Google Form that is linked to Google Sheets for the responses. I also made another Google Sheet file and GAS that will allow me to add response to my Google Form programatically/from code behind. My GAS code is as follows:

```
var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
var form = FormApp.openByUrl(formURL);
formResponse[0] = form.createResponse();
formResponse[0].withItemResponse(items[0].asListItem().createResponse(data[1][0])); //data[1][0] holds my Date response 2011/11/11
formResponse[0].submit();
```

This can successfully add my response in my Google Form. However, I can clearly see in the Google Sheet (for the responses) that the Date is not 2011/11/11 but 2011/11/10. It's always subtracted by one day.

I suspected that it maybe a Timezone issue of the files so I checked both of the Google Sheets' Timezone setting and the script Timezone setting. They are all the same.

Why am I having a different date than the one I submitted in my Form Response? Did I miss anything?

Comment: What is the regional setting of your spreadsheet? What is the cell number format? What is shown on the Apps Script debugger as value of `data[1][0]`?

Answer (score 0):

A Class ListItem requires a String as response. Use `Utilities.formatDate(...)` to convert the Date to a String.

The above because while JavaScript objects have an automatically generated string value, Dates are hard to handle because

- Dates inherit timezone from the spreadsheet settings
- Cell number formatting could make dates be displayed in non-standard ways
- Google Sheets and JavaScript use different EPOCH

Reference

- https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/list-item#createresponseresponse